# PhD student leaving current program for reasons of safety. Recommendations for what to do next in terms of schools and catching up?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, application, harassment

I am a PhD student who lost a year in school due to factors beyond my control.

First, several non-school related issues made it difficult for me to focus on school. Then, a little later, I was harassed and threatened by someone in my program. The harassment continued for a couple of months before I ceased leaving my house altogether. Eventually I talked to the graduate supervisor about the situation. They agreed that it might be best for me to leave for a while. But, I am left with two problems:

1. Most deadlines for schools have past. The ones that haven't, don't seem like a good bet by way of funding. Should I try to find a program to apply to anyway? If not, what can I do to get my year back? I was kind of on a roll before, but now my thought processes feel stagnant and slow — Any recommendations for getting back up to speed?
2. My grades from this year are poor. I do not think they accurately reflect my academic potential or my understanding of the material. Should I be explaining any of the extenuating circumstances to prospective schools when I do apply?

Comment: A fellow student harassed you to shut-in status, and you're the one who had to quit? That seems like nonsense. Your university should be afraid that you will be suing them into the ground, and probably should be giving you a break on the classes you couldn't attend due to harassment. They should be doing everything in their power to fix this for you.

Comment: They did say they would "vouch" for me when I applied to other schools. Though, I am not really clear on what that means. They did renew my fellowship despite the grade dip and I think that might have been them trying to amend the situation.

Comment: @BillBarth Unfortunately, although it is indeed nonsense, it does happen way too much in practice that the victim ends up moving.

Comment: There were other problems that I am hesitant to describe in detail in a public forum. (For anonymity purposes.) 

The harassment was kind of the last straw, I was already really mentally drained. These other problems had to do with my physical location so me leaving is beneficial. Also, I kind of want to leave, I don't like feeling like I can't walk to my office at night to grade or whatever…

Comment: Was it someone on the faculty who harassed you, or a student?

Comment: student. a former friend. or i guess still technically a friend, I just hid from them now..

Comment: I almost get the feeling that your school is trying to get you out the door as quickly as possible so that you don't make a huge stink about the harassment. Here's a test (since you say they would "vouch" for you): Ask them to acknowledge **in writing** your harassment incident.

Comment: I think I don't understand how these things work. The only thing my school has as evidence that this occurred was my personal account. All the harassment occurred outside of the academic buildings. I was afraid of running into the person at school but they couldn't forcibly detain me there. How could I sue the school at all? Why would they be responsible? I made friends with that person. Presumably I made them angry.. Not that this justified their behavior, but I don't see how anyone owes me anything. I really appreciate the input, i just don't understand it.

Comment: This sounds like a circumstance that calls for legal intervention.  You describe intense harassment and forcible detainment. Your former friend's actions are probably illegal, and almost certainly rise to the level of a restraining order.  (I am not a lawyer.)  Please find both counseling and legal help. And please, for your own sake, stop calling the other person your friend; they are not. Friends don't do that.

Comment: You said that you are the only witness, speaking as a tech nerd, forensics enthusiast etc, perhaps you should also consider getting a small camera or microphone disguised as a pen or something and have it with you just in case, i think you can get new ones for $30 or something, video and audio are evidence that should lead to direct arrest. Just in case something happens in the future. Do not threaten them with this however, go straight to the authorities, perhaps also send a copy via e-mail to the faculty so that they cannot deny they were addressed and have to take action.

Comment: Also if it is only one person you could check into self defense, I hear Krav Maga is relatively fast to learn (you can probably learn to handle most situations within the summer) and very effective, it's best to have a back up plan for the future.

Comment: @keyswitch What you describe is a highly illegal behavior. The other person should be expelled from school. There should be no consequences to you, and the school in fact should face negative legal consequences if they interfere with you resolving this matter. As much as I'm anti-lawsuit, you have every moral right to sue the school to the ground if they interfere. What you describe is highly troubling. The fact that no physical violence has occurred doesn't lessen how grave a situation it is.

Comment: @user3079666 Recording someone without their permission or knowledge is highly illegal ($2,500 + 1 year jail) depending on the jurisdiction. And while a martial art is very good for confidence, the motivation is to avoid physical confrontations, not to use the techniques on a harasser. I could see martial arts, over time, turn someone into a person with visible self confidence who others would not harass, even if they were unaware of that person's training. However an ill conceived plan to use force could backfire, leading to the harasser hurting the OP, or taking legal action against them.

Comment: If the OP wishes to practice martial arts that may boost their confidence. And if they have someone to be a material witness that is better than a recording. I believe the best action for them would be to file a formal complaint of harassment through the school, even as the only witness the school *must* investigate. And if the harasser has any further contact the OP can go to the local police and ask if criminal charges, or at least a retraining order, are possible.

Comment: @keyswitch (above I suggest that recording without permission is a bad idea) However, if the harasser sends any electronic communication that could be construed as harassing they open the door for you to take those communications to the police. Electronic threats are covered under [U.S. Code 18 Chapter 41 subsection 875(c)](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/875#c) and carry a maximum sentence of 5 years in prison and/or a fine of up to $5,000.

Comment: @kleineg I think recording in public is not illegal,I of course do not know the specifics, but shooting video in public certainly is not.Plus, in harassment, it's about proving you are being harassed, I can't see any judge holding it against you when you are the victim (as in self defence).Granted,if you can prove it without recording that's best, but a recording is undeniable. As for martial arts, it's best to be prepared - by no means provoke or strike first, but not be vulnerable. And what you said about confidence is very important indeed, a confident fellow is less likely to be picked on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the department is 'on the hook' to do more than just vouch for you (whatever that means). Sit down with your advisor and the graduate supervisor. Work with them to identify programs which would be a good match for your research plans and with which they or other department members have strong ties. They should be working their networks to help you transfer as easily as possible.

If you're only a year in, you might also want to think about whether you want to cleanly start over at the new university--retake any classes, etc. as opposed to trying to get credit for any classes you passed in your current program. Were you accepted to other programs before? See if one of those are still a good match.

I know you want to move for various reasons, and you may not want to do anything with the person who harassed you. However, if that person is not getting punished, counseled, or something, the problem is likely to recur with someone else. Ask the department to do something, if only to require the person to undergo a psychological evaluation.

Comment: Yes, the only reason I decided to tell anyone in the first place was that I figured they were going through some serious mental issues because of their behavior and that they needed help. The grad supervisor said that they would make sure that people talked to the person, and last time I asked how they were doing the supervisor said the person in question seemed to be doing better.

Comment: I can't tell how much of their harassment was intentional, they were just very controlling of who i interacted with–they threatened to beat up someone who had talked to me, in a particularly impassioned way that was a little disturbing because it was so disproportionate to the situation. Also, sometimes they wouldn't let me go home. They told me I could go when they were done talking... and they made lots of "jokes" about killing me or raping me, often at the very same time that they were keeping me from going home. 

But they didn't physically hurt me at all. Is that punishable behavior?

Comment: @keyswitch Yes, that behavior you describe is punishable. You have suffered emotional abuse and lost a year of precious time in your studies, and this creep is still wandering around not having been dealt with in the proper way.

Comment: ...by the police.

Comment: You bet that is punishable, harassment and sexual harassment, physical threats and so on are things that I could easily see in the police report.

Comment: I know everyone else has said this as well, but this is certainly a level at which it should be taken to the authorities (i.e. police).  It isn't just 2-3 random people on internet telling it to you(I guess we're still random but there are lots of us), but it seems to be a consensus that this is a serious crime and both the school and police should be involved.  Abuse of any kind is heinous regardless of the emotional state of the other person; one should have learned to control themselves and their actions by this point.

Comment: Now, one factor that not everyone here is considering is *which country* this story is taking place. The answers and comments here are certainly relevant for at least North America and Western Europe (and surely other places that I don't know as well), but might not be appropriate in other places. For example, in some North-African countries, there is a history of women getting in serious trouble for reporting harassment to the police.

Comment: @keyswitch You worry about the other person entirely too much. It speaks positively about your character that you do so, but it's way past that at this point. The net effect of what that person has done to you is to take a year away from your life. Think about it. It's like if you had been jailed. If someone tells you that you can't leave "until", that's illegal arrest or kidnapping.